# Page content div and minimum height

Tags: html, height, css

My site currently has this general layout for all pages:

```
<?php
include "head.php";
?>
<title></title>
<?php
include "top.php";
?>
<div class="mainbody">
</div>
<?php
include "bottom.php";
?>
```

head.php includes the html and head stuff (ie, the topmost things on a page), top.php includes the site logo and the horizontal navbar, bottom.php includes the footer and closing html/body tags, and the mainbody class contains the content for the specific page.

Now my problem is on one specific page. On every page, there is enough content for the page to be large enough that it needs to be scrollable, and the mainbody div expands to accommodate that. The issue with one of my pages is that there is too little content, or rather, most of the content is floated, so the div doesn't expand as it normally does. I thought I could fix it by adding a min-height to the CSS, but this doesn't work. The CSS currently looks like this:

```
.mainbody {
background-image: url("Images/Background.png");
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 0.7%;
position: relative;
width: 68%;
min-height: 80%;
min-width: 768px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Every single line works, except for min-height. I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the value of min-height in pixels

```
min-height: 400px;
```

Here is a fiddle to show you

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/2pEwa/)

**Addition**

To do this pure css you need to add some css to the body like so

```
 body {position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; overflow:visible; }
 #content { background-color:#cccccc; min-height:80%; }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/2pEwa/4/)

Comment: I was afraid of that. Won't this cause problems for mobile users? Is there no way at all to get percentage to work?

Comment: I'm not following how it would fail for mobile users...You could set the height dynamically with jquery, or javascript if you'd like...but it seems like overkill for this situation.

Comment: @user1583168 Here is an example using jquery http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/2pEwa/1/

Comment: @user1583168 I found a pure css solution, see my revised answer

Comment: That did it! Absolute legend you are! Cheers! If I don't mind asking here, is there some way to allow the height to change based on floated content? I'm assuming not, but I might as well ask.

Comment: @user1583168 Glad it helps you!  As far as your question, I am not sure what you mean?  For now, check out this fiddle, it shows how to clear floats. This may help you http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/NBf3v/

Comment: Hmm, not quite what I'm looking for, but I think I'll leave it for another thread. Thanks though.

Comment: If you can elaborate on what you want, I may be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the floats? You said that the content is floated, and it causes the mainbody div not to expand.

You could also use a sticky footer technique, like [this one](http://www.mindfly.com/blog/2012/08/09/the-css-sticky-footer-fix/). There are few sticky footer snippets floating around the web, just pick what works for you best. :)

Comment: I think you will have to elaborate a little on this. While it doesn't expand in the sense that I cant get a percentage-based min-height to work, it will expand if there is collapsible/expandable content.